# MS SpeechRecognitionEngine not returning results

Tags: .net, powershell, speech-recognition, sapi

i am trying to do some simple speech recognition (from a .wav file) using Powershell. I am using `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine`. Sadly i have some serious problems with it, but first off here is my code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0\Assembly\Microsoft.Speech.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Speech")


$cult = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

$listener = New-Object Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine($cult)
$listener.SetInputToWaveFile("C:\Users\user\Downloads\audio.wav")

$arr = @("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q" ,"r", "s", "t", "u","v","w","x","y","z","four","red")
$text = New-Object Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.Choices
$text.Add($arr)
$toGram = New-Object Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder($text)
$toGram.Culture = $cult
$gram = New-Object Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.Grammar($toGram)
$listener.LoadGrammar($gram)

Register-ObjectEvent $listener RecognizeCompleted -SourceIdentifier "RecognizeCompleted" -Action {if($EventArgs){$EventArgs.Result.Text; write-host $EventArgs.Result.Confidence} else {write-host "nope"} }
$listener.RecognizeAsync()
```

My problem is that when i use `.Recognize()` i get no output at all, not even output with 0 results.
When registering for the completion of the Async method (`.RecognizeAsync()`) the Handler gets called and `$EventArgs` does exist but i can not access any Properties of the variable or even get output from `Get-Member`.

Am i doing something obviously wrong here? I would appreciate any input as i´m kind of going mad right now...

I would also be open for any alternatives to the MS Speech API (any command line tool that can do basic speech recognition in english would do).

**Update:** the wave file contains a series of letters or numbers. For example " 3 D 6 H Y"

**Update:** i appreciate edits but i dont appreciate someone removing code! Thanks! Dont do it!

**Update:** it seems SAPI doesnt handle single characters very well (if anyhow). I´ll probably try sphinx next. Thanks though to brandon for investing so much time to help me.

Comment: For the recognition engine to be able to recognize any of those characters, the .wav file should be only one of those "words". So if your .wav file is anything other than a single character (spoken "A" through "Z") or the word "red" or "four", it's not going to recognize anything. In short: what's in your wav file?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't see the commented bit up there. Hold on, commenting

Comment: I added an answer to summarize everything

Comment: [There is a better way](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0b2a0a4f-df68-486b-8249-735f7c4fad4e/graceful-way-to-create-an-alphabet-array) to generate an array of alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from my removed comment as it's part of the answer:

`Recognize()` is blocking. It's doing one single recognition action each call the way you have it now. I don't have any experience with Powershell so correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you'd have call that function or procedure or script etc... for every time you want a recognition.

Basically: If it hears "A", that's it; You have to call `Recognize` again to get "B". Try it with a microphone (`SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice`). Lastly, `Recognize[Async]()` raises the `SpeechRecognized` event, where you retrieve results, which it doesn't look like you handle.

You'll probably want to call `RecognizeAsync` instead, so the engine can handle more than one bit of spoken text in the same action. It can be done both ways however.

Again, because I'm not familiar with Powershell, here's some pseudo/c# code to get you on the right track:

`Recognize()` method:

```
function InitializeRecognizer
    setup your recognizer and audio input, .wav file etc.
    add the handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
    call the Recognize method

function SpeechRecognizedHandler
    read the EventArgs data to get the speech element
    do your output or logic
    if we want to listen to some more stuff
        call Recognize() again
```

`RecognizeAsync()` method:

```
function InitializeRecognizer
    setup your recognizer and audio input, .wav file etc.
    add the handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
    call the RecognizeAsync() method

function SpeechRecognizedHandler
    read the EventArgs data to get the speech element
    do your output or logic
    (Note: you may have to call RecognizeAsyncCancel()
       or something similar here if you run into issues 
       where it's recognizing stuff in a weird order)
```

Here's a link to the `RecognizeAsync()` MSDN doc, which will show you the events raised by the `Recognize` family.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizeasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation, especially regarding `recognize()` (didn´t expect it to work like that). I will try to handle the `SpeechRecognized` event and report back!

Comment: Cool. Let me know how you get on

Comment: Ok i have now tested with a handler for `SpeechRecognized `but no success yet. I actually get some output from the EventArgs of the `RecognizeCompleted` Handler now (with an empty result field) so its probably just because it doesnt recognize anything... i have uploaded one of the wav files i´m testing with if anyone is interested to try it out: http://1drv.ms/1tF729M . Do you have any other suggestions i could try to get it to recognize this? It´s not like there´s much noise in the file so i´m quite disappointed it doesnt recognize anything

Comment: Is it calling your `SpeechRecognized` handler? Have you tried with the Microphone?

Comment: just tried with a microphone but it doesnt recognize anything, the `RecognizeCompleted` Handler gets called about 5-6 seconds in with empty error and result field and Cancelled = False

Comment: Have you tried the `SpeechRecognized` event, and not the `RecognizeCompleted` event?

Comment: sure i have handlers set up for both of them and since the result item is empty i´d guess it doesnt detect anything (i really tried hard :)) Ok now i get a call, it seems it doesnt recognize single characters at all, if i put some words in my grammar file it works ok

Comment: I just downloaded the example found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and it ran no problem, but it didn't match the text in your wav file (which I downloaded as well). Try changing from "A"-"Z" to "This is a test item" and speak that phrase into the microphone. I think the recognizer can't handle characters very well. "W" for example becomes "Double you"

Comment: so my previous comment was a bit premature as i falsly interpreted some output from the `recognizedCompleted` handler as output from the other one... i added a few words and phrases but even that doesnt work (no call to `SpeechRecognized` at all). Is there an option to load a default "grammar" so i could try if it recognizes anything in my file at all so i could at least parse that output and try to "reverse engineer" it someway?

Comment: There is no default grammar. Again, you can create one with more recognizable phrases in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66155/discussion-between-brandon-and-paul).