# MS SpeechRecognitionEngine doesn't always return when reading WAV files

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, sapi

There is a similar question that [already exists here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277744/ms-speechrecognitionengine-not-returning-results), but the solution does not apply to my situation, and [they ultimately never solved the problem anyways](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20268129#20268129).

So, as the title suggests, the `recognizer.Recognize()` function doesn't always return, doesn't even seem to be throwing an error that I can see, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. It returns consistently for one of my test WAV files (we'll call this one *working.wav*), but never ever returns for my other file (*failing.wav*). These files are created the same way and simply contain a brief (8 seconds) recording of the same person asking different questions. They both have a similar period of silence at the start, and the question itself ends after about 3-4 seconds, with about 4 seconds of silence at the end of the recording.

I've loaded grammars, tried both default (empty) grammar and this custom one, and I am handling `SpeechDetected()`, `SpeechRecognized()` and `SpeechRecognitionRejected()`. None of these events get called for *failing.wav*, but they work for *working.wav*.

I had also tried setting the `BabbleTimeout`, `EndSilenceTimeout`, `EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous` and `InitialSilenceTimeout` properties to be around 1 second each, but these made no difference either, so I removed them.

```
public string ReadQuestion()
{
    RecognitionResult recResults;
    string question = "Is this a default question?"; //default question for debug purposes

    using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")))
    {
        GrammarBuilder areYou = new GrammarBuilder("Are you");
        areYou.AppendDictation();

        Choices anActor = new Choices(new GrammarBuilder[] { areYou });
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar((GrammarBuilder)anActor);
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(grammar);

        //wav file generated by UE4
        recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(@"..\..\..\..\..\Saved\BouncedWavFiles\question.wav");

        recognizer.SpeechDetected +=
            new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechDetected);

        recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
            new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

        recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected +=
            new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entering STT...");
            recResults =  recognizer.Recognize();
            Console.WriteLine("Leaving STT...");

            question = recResults.Text;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught exception " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    return question;
}
```

Of course, one could simply call `RecognizeAsync()` and cancel after a short timeout, but that defeats the purpose of, you know, having a functional speech recognition engine, since it's failing to return very often and for seemingly arbitrary reasons.

If anyone would have any insight whatsoever about why `Recognize()` stalls, or even ways I could better debug this, I would be really grateful.

Comment: your problem is always here?

Comment: yes. i haven't touched this code in a while, but it was never solved.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @Mickey, no, sorry :(

Comment: I ended up finding a solution that at least works for me. The wav files I generated were 24 bit wav files. The speech recognition would freeze anytime I called the Recognize method. I changed it to 16 bit wav files and it works without an issue. So either the speech recognition library doesn't like 24 bit waves or it dies whenever the kbits/s are too high.

Comment: oh heck, good catch. i'll have to remember this next time i work with the library!